# Select value in p-dropdown from PrimeNG using Cypress

Tags: html, angular, typescript, cypress

I try to select a value in my dropdown list using Cypress. I have tried several ways to do so, but none of them worked. It always select the value that is already selected.

In the Cypress documenation I found this:

```
cy.get('select').select('apples').should('have.value', '456')
```

When I apply this on my code ... :

```
cy.get('select').select('FR').should('have.value', 'FR')
```

... I get this error:
CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.select() failed because this element is not visible:

```
<select class="ng-tns-c16-2" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Nederlands">...</select>
```

This element '' is not visible because its content is being clipped by one of its parent elements, which has a CSS property of overflow: 'hidden', 'scroll' or 'auto'

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.

https://on.cypress.io/element-cannot-be-interacted-with

When I use force:true, the error is skipped, but it still doesn't work.

```
cy.get('select').select('FR',{force:true}).should('have.value', 'FR')
```

I also tried it without using select, but using click. This also just select the selected one, not the third selected.

```
cy.get('option').eq(2).click({force: true});
```

Using .type({downarrow}) also fails because it is not a text input field.

So I'm really out of ideas right now.

I want to test multiptle dropdowns, this is one of them:

```
<span class="eco-form-component__control">
            <p-dropdown formControlName="sector"
                        [options]="sectors"
                        [style]="{'width':'100%'}">
            </p-dropdown>
</span>
```

EDIT:

I also tried the following, here I get the right value (France), but he cannot click on it.

```
  cy.get('p-dropdown[formControlName="provenanceCountry"]').click();
    cy.get('p-dropdown[formControlName="provenanceCountry"]').get('select').then(option => {
      cy.wrap(option).get('p-dropdown[formControlName="provenanceCountry"]').contains('FRANCE').click();
    });
```

Error:

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this
>   element is not visible:

```
 <option class="ng-tns-c9-15 ng-star-inserted" value="[object
 Object]">FRANCE</option>
```

> This element `'<option.ng-tns-c9-15.ng-star-inserted>'` is not visible
>   because it has an effective width and height of: '0 x 0' pixels.
>
> Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.
>
> https://on.cypress.io/element-cannot-be-interacted-with

When I use {force: true} in my click, the error is just not shown.

EXACT HTML:

```
<div _ngcontent-c11="" class="eco-form-component"><label _ngcontent-c11="" class="eco-form-component__label" ng-reflect-ng-class="eco-form-component__label"> Geïmporteerd uit </label><span _ngcontent-c11="" class="eco-form-component__control"><p-dropdown _ngcontent-c11="" formcontrolname="provenanceCountry" class="ng-tns-c14-7 ui-inputwrapper-filled ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" ng-reflect-style="[object Object]" ng-reflect-options="[object Object],[object Object" ng-reflect-name="provenanceCountry"><div class="ng-tns-c14-7 ui-dropdown ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="width: 100%;"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible ng-tns-c14-7 ng-star-inserted"><select class="ng-tns-c14-7" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" aria-label=" "><!--bindings={}--><!--bindings={}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><!----><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><option class="ng-tns-c14-7 ng-star-inserted" value=" "> </option><option class="ng-tns-c14-7 ng-star-inserted" value="BELGIUM">BELGIUM</option><option class="ng-tns-c14-7 ng-star-inserted" value="FRANCE">FRANCE</option><!----></select></div><div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><input class="ng-tns-c14-7" readonly="" role="listbox" type="text" aria-label=" "></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><label class="ng-tns-c14-7 ui-dropdown-label ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><!----> <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet-context": "[object Object]"
}--></label><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={}--><!--bindings={}--><div class="ui-dropdown-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right"><span class="ui-dropdown-trigger-icon ui-clickable pi pi-caret-down" ng-reflect-klass="ui-dropdown-trigger-icon ui-cl" ng-reflect-ng-class="pi pi-caret-down"></span></div><!--bindings={}--></div></p-dropdown></span><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></div>
```

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: I think the problem is like asked here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/695 
When I run this:   `cy.get('p-dropdown[formControlName="provenanceCountry"]').click();
    cy.wait(1000);
    cy.contains('FRANCE').click();` I get this error:
`<option class="ng-tns-c9-13 ng-star-inserted" value="FRANCE">FRANCE</option>
retrying: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible:
This element '<option.ng-tns-c9-13.ng-star-inserted>' is not visible because it has an effective width and height of: '0 x 0' pixels.`

Comment: maybe.. hard to say without having access to the actual app itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the website of PrimeNG this is the output of a `p-dropdown`-tag:

```html
<p-dropdown optionlabel="name" placeholder="Select a City" class="ng-tns-c3-1 ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
    <div class="ng-tns-c3-1 ui-dropdown ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-dropdown-clearable" style="width: 129px;">
        <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible ng-tns-c3-1 ng-star-inserted">
            <select class="ng-tns-c3-1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" aria-label=" ">
                <option class="ng-tns-c3-1 ng-star-inserted">Select a City</option>
                <option class="ng-tns-c3-1 ng-star-inserted" value="[object Object]">New York</option>
                <option class="ng-tns-c3-1 ng-star-inserted" value="[object Object]">Rome</option>
                <option class="ng-tns-c3-1 ng-star-inserted" value="[object Object]">London</option>
                <option class="ng-tns-c3-1 ng-star-inserted" value="[object Object]">Istanbul</option>
                <option class="ng-tns-c3-1 ng-star-inserted" value="[object Object]">Paris</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
            <input class="ng-tns-c3-1" readonly="" role="listbox" type="text" aria-label=" ">
            </div>
            <label class="ng-tns-c3-1 ui-dropdown-label ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-placeholder ng-star-inserted">Select a City</label>
            <div class="ui-dropdown-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right">
                <span class="ui-dropdown-trigger-icon ui-clickable pi pi-caret-down"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p-dropdown>
```

However if we take something more styled theme of PrimeNG like the 'Ultima' theme, we get this:

```html
<p-dropdown class="ng-tns-c4-30 ui-inputwrapper-filled ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
    <div class="ng-tns-c4-30 ui-dropdown ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-dropdown-open">
        <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
            <input class="ng-tns-c4-30" readonly="" role="listbox" type="text" aria-label="Select City">
            </div>
            <label class="ng-tns-c4-30 ui-dropdown-label ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ng-star-inserted">
                Select City
            </label>
            <div class="ui-dropdown-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right">
                <span class="ui-dropdown-trigger-icon ui-clickable pi pi-caret-down"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="ng-trigger ng-trigger-overlayAnimation ng-tns-c4-30 ui-dropdown-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ng-star-inserted" style="z-index: 1002; top: 23px; left: 0px; transform: translateY(0px); opacity: 1;">
                <div class="ui-dropdown-items-wrapper" style="max-height: 200px;">
                    <ul class="ui-dropdown-items ui-dropdown-list ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset">
                        <li class="ng-tns-c4-30 ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ng-star-inserted" style="">
                            <span class="ng-tns-c4-30 ng-star-inserted">Select City</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="ng-tns-c4-30 ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all ng-star-inserted" style="">
                            <span class="ng-tns-c4-30 ng-star-inserted">New York</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="ng-tns-c4-30 ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all ng-star-inserted" style="">
                            <span class="ng-tns-c4-30 ng-star-inserted">Rome</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="ng-tns-c4-30 ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all ng-star-inserted" style="">
                            <span class="ng-tns-c4-30 ng-star-inserted">London</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="ng-tns-c4-30 ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all ng-star-inserted" style="">
                            <span class="ng-tns-c4-30 ng-star-inserted">Istanbul</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="ng-tns-c4-30 ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all ng-star-inserted" style="">
                            <span class="ng-tns-c4-30 ng-star-inserted">Paris</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p-dropdown>
```

In the first case cypress shouldn't run in that much trouble.  However in the second case, the one I believe you are having, cypress will run in some trouble.

In the first case this will probably work without any problem because it searches for `<select>` and after that the `<option>`-tags( .select() searches for the `<option>`-tags):

```js
cy.get('select').select('London')
```

In the second case we don't have any `<select>` or `<option>`-tags.. So we have to find another solution. I am unable to run local at the moment but here is my guess for your problem:

```js
cy.get('p-dropdown[formControlName="provenanceCountry"]').click().find('ul li > span').contains('France').click();
```

or if I read the documentation correctly and `.contains()` has indeed the option to pass selectors:

```js
cy.get('p-dropdown[formControlName="provenanceCountry"]').click().contains('ul li > span', 'France').click();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Both of your solutions are working fine!

When using your first solution, cypress will check all the values in the dropdown, one by one. In your second solution, without using 'find', Cypress does not check all the values. So performance-wise the second solution is the best one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found one solutions this instruction selected the first option.
version "cypress": "^9.1.0"

```html
cy.get('p-dropdown[formControlName="category"]')
.find('.p-dropdown')
.click({ force: true })
.find('.p-dropdown-items-wrapper > .p-dropdown-items')
.click({ force: true })
.get('.p-dropdown-item')
.children()
.first()
.click({ force: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Not familiar with angular, but it seems the generated HTML for `<option>` has `value` attr set to `[object Object]` which means you're passing an object to it instead of a primitive value which can be serialized via its `.toString()` method.

Also note, that if you can't use `<options>`'s  `value` attribute for some reason (e.g. it's not present), cypress' `.select()` also considers the textContent value (the text between the `<option>` tags):

```
describe('test', () => {
    it('test', () => {
        cy.window().then( win => {
            win.document.write(`
                <select>
                    <option>empty</option>
                    <option value="nyc">New York</option>
                    <option>Paris</option>
                </select>
            `);
        });
        cy.get('select').select('nyc'); // value attribute
        cy.get('select').select('Paris'); // textContent value
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** from the HTML code you posted, it seems you're not calling `cy.select()` on a `<select>` element, which you should:

```
cy.get('[formcontrolname="provenanceCountry"]').find('select').select('FRANCE');
```

Comment: I changed the value attr to a string, but nothing changed: cy.get('p-dropdown[formControlName="provenanceCountry"]').select('FRANCE'); Now I get an error saying y.select() can only be called on a <select>. (Your subject is a: <p-dropdown _ngcontent-c13="" formcontrolname="provenanceCountry" )

Comment: It seems the angular template engine is rendering the dropdown as a custom HTML, not using standard `<select>`. Can you post the exact HTML of `p-dropdown[formControlName="provenanceCountry"]'` that you're working with? You can do that using chrome's devtools elements panel, find the DOM element, right-clicking it and a selecting `copy` → `copy outerHTML`.

Comment: I'll edit my post for the exact HTML , because it's too long to fit here

Comment: After EDIT: Now I get a visibility error: CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.select() failed because this element is not visible:

<select class="ng-tns-c9-15" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" aria-label=" ">...</select>

This element '<select.ng-tns-c9-15>' is not visible because its content is being clipped by one of its parent elements, which has a CSS property of overflow: 'hidden', 'scroll' or 'auto'

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.

Comment: Can't repro that from the minimal example you posted, possibly because of missing CSS etc. Either post a full working example on jsfiddle or similar service so that I can repro fully, or just use `{ force: true }` if you think cypress is mistaken.

Comment: It's nothing more than this: https://jsfiddle.net/remco123/9vbp4ofm It is not a working fiddle, but now you have a better idea I guess

Comment: { force: true } doesn't work here, if I you think of something else I can show, please let me know

Comment: To make that jsfiddle work, you'd need to include angular and write a minimal app that renders that template into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the above `HTML` given in the question. Using the cypress `invoke` text method, received all the drop-down list box `text` and passed into a `getCityText(text)` function as an argument. Then I have assigned the text received into an array called `listText`. Further, I have removed all the extra things that found inside the array, like `newlines, commas, carriage returns` etc. Then return the proper array value and later `assert` it with `actual vs expected`. Now the test is passing successfully.

The reason why I have to choose an extra `js function` is to handle the following assertion error that cypress was throwing ..`expected **, , BELGIUM, FRANCE, ** to deeply equal [ BELGIUM, FRANCE ]`
Happy to know if any other easy way to handle newlines, commas etc

```
describe('Verify the list box values are selected', function () {
        it.only('Test the drop down values', function () {
         cy.visit('urlgoeshere')
         cy.get('select[aria-hidden="true"]').parents('.ui-helper-clearfix').find('div').find('select').invoke('text')
            .then(text=>{
              var finalArr =  new Array();
              finalArr = getCityText(text);
              console.log(finalArr);
              expect(finalArr).to.contain(['BELGIUM', 'FRANCE'])
               })
            })
        })
```

// Function which handles the text received and return values after removing all un necessary 'new lines, commas etc'

```
function getCityText(text){
  var listText = new Array();
  var trimText;
  listText = text;
  for(var i=0; i<=listText.length; i++){
    trimText = listText.replace(/\n|\r+/g, ' ');
    var nText = trimText.trim();
    var fText = nText.replace(" ", ",")
  }
  return fText;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I have applied this to my code and this works well :) I will use this in my tests. But the problem is that I have to click/select an item in the dropdown list. Because the dropdown list is empty by default and they can't be empty to continue to the next page. You have an idea how i can select an item?

Comment: Can you please try `cy.get('select[aria-hidden="true"]').select('BELGIUM').should('have.value', 'BELGIUM')` ...this should select a value from a drop down. If that is working, can you accept my answer, so that I will get the internet points :)

Comment: I would love to accept your answer, but it is still not working. Still the same error: timed out retrying: cy.select() failed because this element is not visible:

<select class="ng-tns-c9-14" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" aria-label=" ">...</select>

This element '<select.ng-tns-c9-14>' is not visible because its content is being clipped by one of its parent elements, which has a CSS property of overflow: 'hidden', 'scroll' or 'auto'

Comment: Can you please post the complete `HTML` of that page where the select drop down in available

Comment: Remco, I have updated my answer, can you please try that one ...`cy.get('select[aria-hidden="true"]').parents('.ui-helper-clearfix').find('div').find('select').invoke('text')
            .then(text=>{
              var finalArr =  new Array();
              finalArr = getCityText(text);
              console.log(finalArr);              
              expect(finalArr).to.contain(['BELGIUM', 'FRANCE'])
            })`

Comment: That works perfect when you want to check the values inside the dropdown. But I want to select one of the values. He always complains that the element, where I do the select on, is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me... You need to provide force option true in click event**

```
cy.get('p-dropdown[formControlName="countryName"]').click().contains('ul li > span', 'France').parent('li').click({force: true});
```